# Create drupal content programmatically with custom entity ( assets )

Tags: media

I am using asset module : https://www.drupal.org/project/asset

I creates a new entity type = asset. I get a form where I can add ( document, image, video..).

How can I, from a custom module add a content of asset ? I think that I cannot do it the way we creat nodes ... like :

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "asset";
node_object_prepare($node);
....
```

Please help

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right code:

```
function create_assets(){

$asset = entity_create('asset' , array('type' =>'image'));
$asset->title = 'image publication';
//$asset->field_asset_image = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => get_external_image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/drupal/img/logo.png"))));
$asset->field_alt["und"][0]["value"] = "alt image publication";
//$asset->save();
entity_save('asset', $asset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use core and EntityAPI methods for this task like this:

```
$asset = entity_get_controller('asset');
$asset->type = 'MY_TYPE';
$asset->... = '...';
....

$asset->save();
```

Comment: I'am trying this. Get back  very soon.